# NuGet System.Data.SQLite - Listing all versions on NuGet

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, nuget

i have had a serious problem with sqlite versions falling out of sync. I'm sitting with a System.Data.SQLite.dll that says assembly version = 1.0.66.0

i'm trying to attach NuGet to pick up the assembly but it says the package doesn't exist.

```
<package id="System.Data.SQLite" version="1.0.66.0" targetFramework="net35" />
```

I have noticed that everytime the developers roll out a new version the old version disappear. I don't know if this is an error or if the developers are intentionally removing the old versions.

Eitherway i seem to be able to pick up old versions if i write in the packages.config or in the console. But i must know the *excact* version number. Which is not the assembly version sadly.

How can i get the version history for this package?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite

Comment: The developers de-list the old versions. I honestly have no idea why.

Comment: I'd recommend using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SQLite/ over System.Data.SQLite. It's a much better library IMO.

Comment: @kjbartel noted, imho Entity Framework is a pain in the ass to configure on new projects. I'm looking looking for alternatives, I'll try this package on my next project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There currently seems to be a server-side bug on NuGet preventing the ability to list all versions of unlisted packages using Package Manager and nuget.exe.
See https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/3274

However, the NuGet search API can still be queried to return them:
https://api-v2v3search-0.nuget.org/search/query?q=packageid:System.Data.Sqlite&ignoreFilter=true&prerelease=true&take=40

Another way is to use [NuGet Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer):

1. Launch NuGet Package Explorer
2. Select "Open a package from online feed (Ctrl+G)"
3. Package source: https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
4. Search for `system.data.sqlite`
5. Select `System.Data.SQLite`
6. Select `show all versions`
7. Use the mouse wheel to scroll through the list of versions

I'm not exactly sure why the developers do this but it seems intentional, according to the [news](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki) and [support](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/support.wiki) pages:

> Release packages for non-current releases will be archived.

Comment: a bug that has been unattended for almost 2 years? Sadly it seems more like it's by design rather than a bug.

Comment: @CyberFox, I also added another method using NuGet Package Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

> PM> get-package -listavailable -Filter System.Data.SQLite -AllVersions
>   | Select-Object ID, Version, Description, DownloadCount | Sort-Object
>   -Descending -Property DownloadCount

Comment: this doesn't list all versions for System.Data.SQLite

Comment: it actually does. try with other packages. seems sqlite deletes older versions. you can also try `find-package -id sqlite` for nuget version > 3.

Comment: That's my point exactly. But even if the developers delete the old versions it still seems somewhat accessible under Package Statistics where you can find some of the old versions. But not all. I should probably contact someone about this.